# IIS7 error config and remote errors

Tags: iis, iis-7.5, custom-errors

Certain IIS7/7.5 `500.19` configuration errors only render on a browser running on the local server.

This appears to happen regardless of whether I set `<httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" existingResponse="PassThrough" />` in the `system.webServer` section of a site's `web.config` file (or even globally for that matter).

For example, I had a developer who reported that he was just getting the generic IIS7 500 error page:

[image]

This was happening even though he had the following configured in his `web.config`:

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" existingResponse="PassThrough" />
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

If I browse to the site on the server itself I see (some sensitive info redacted):
[image]

Would the reason for this be that if the `web.config` has errors it therefore can't be parsed. Because it can't be parsed the local `<httpErrors>` setting doesn't get read and thus causes IIS to revert to default settings (i.e. DetailedLocalOnly)?

**Update:**

[@LazyOne](https://serverfault.com/questions/285298/iis7-error-config-and-remote-errors#comment-267516) - suggested setting the above config at the server level which I already tried. This resulted in just raw 500 errors:

[image]

Comment: _"Because it can't be parsed the local <httpErrors> setting doesn't get read and thus causes IIS to revert to default settings (i.e. DetailedLocalOnly)?"_ -- You can quickly test this theory by changing error response mode for the **whole** server (which is "detailed local and custom for remote" by default): IIS Manager | Error Pages | Edit Feature Settings...

Comment: @lazyone - see my update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having poked around some more, I've worked out how to get `500.19` errors to appear remotely even if the site `web.config` is clobbered.

The trick is to set (globally) `errorMode="Detailed"` and **`existingResponse="Replace"`**.

The `existingResponse="Replace"` setting is a bit counter intuitive but does make sense.